# Can’t get "play/pause" of window 1. Access not allowed. - trying to unpause movie through Applescript

Tags: applescript, automator, mojave, quicktime

I'm trying to pause/unpause QuickTime Player with a little dictation command:

```
on run
    activate application "QuickTime Player"
    tell application "System Events"
        click "play/pause" of window 1
    end tell
end run
```

When I test this, I get the error message `Can’t get "play/pause" of window 1. Access not allowed.` Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code instead of a picture of it.  Is there a particular reason you are trying to script the user interface instead of just using terms from QuickTime Player's scripting dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question. And there is no reason I'm trying to script the UI, I was just unaware there is scripting dictionaries. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer to my question is to use the scripting dictionary for QTP instead of the using the UI. The website I got my code from is [here](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=28847) and the code I'm using is below:

```
set movieFile to (path to me) & name of front window of application "QuickTime Player"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    try
        set isPlaying to get playing of document 1
    on error
        open movieFile
    end try
    if isPlaying is true then
    else
        set the looping of document 1 to true
        play document 1
    end if
end tell
```